# Verify Python socket is encrypted

Tags: python, sockets, ssl, encryption, tcp

I've made a TCP echo client/server with bits from [here](https://pymotw.com/2/socket/tcp.html) and [here](http://carlo-hamalainen.net/blog/2013/1/24/python-ssl-socket-echo-test-with-self-signed-certificate). How can I verify that the socket is encrypted and cannot be intercepted and read? I've tried using Wireshark, but both SSL and non-SSL show encrypted packets. This makes me question their validity.

**Client:**

```
import socket
import ssl

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_address = ('HOSTNAME', 10000)
print('Connecting to %s port %s' % server_address)
sock.connect(server_address)
ssl_sock = ssl.wrap_socket(
        sock,
        ssl_version = ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2
)

try:
    message = str.encode(input('>>> '))
    print('Sending "%s"' % message)
    ssl_sock.sendall(message)

    amount_received = 0
    amount_expected = len(message)

    while amount_received < amount_expected:
        data = ssl_sock.recv(16)
        amount_received += len(data)
        print('Received "%s"' % data)

finally:
    print('Closing socket')
    ssl_sock.close()
```

**Server:**

```
import socket
import ssl

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_address = ('HOSTNAME', 10000)
print('Starting up on %s port %s' % server_address)
sock.bind(server_address)
sock.listen(1)

while True:
    print('Waiting for a connection')
    try:
        connection, client_address = sock.accept()
        stream = ssl.wrap_socket(
            connection,
            server_side = True,
            certfile = 'fullchain.pem',
            keyfile = 'privkey.pem',
            ssl_version = ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2
        )
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('\nStopping server')
        exit()
    except:
        print('ERROR')
        continue

    try:
        print('Connection from', client_address)

        while True:
            data = stream.recv(16)
            print('Received "%s"' % data)
            if data:
                print('Sending data back to the client')
                stream.sendall(data)
            else:
                print('No more data from', client_address)
                break
    finally:
        stream.close()
```

The server is running on my VPS and using the real certificate for HTTPS. Everything works, but I just want to be sure this test is secure before I build anything for real.